# Rock, Paper, Scissors – wrong outcome

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I tried to make rock paper scissors game. And I'm here stuck on one problem. I have no idea how to fix it. So the problem is when I type in "paper" and "ranval" variable choices 2 (scissors) I still win. Thank you a lot for your time. There is the code:

```
import random
while True: # 0 rock, 1 paper, 2 scissors
    while True:
        rps = [0, 1, 2]
        ranval = random.choice(rps)
        choice = str(input("(r)ock, (p)aper or (s)cissors?"))

    if choice.lower() == "r" or "rock":

        if ranval == 0:
            print("TIE!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 1:
            print("YOU LOST!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 2:
            print("YOU WON!", ranval)
            break

    if choice.lower() == "p" or "paper":

        if ranval == 0:
            print("YOU WON!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 1:
            print("TIE!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 2:
            print("YOU LOST!", ranval)
            break

    if choice.lower() == "s" or "scissors":
        if ranval == 0:
            print("YOU LOST!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 1:
            print("YOU WON!", ranval)
            break
        elif ranval == 2:
            print("TIE!", ranval)
            break

    if choice.lower() == "e" or "exit":
        exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

`if choice.lower() == "r" or == "rock":`

`if choice.lower() == "r" or choice.lower() == "rock":`

are different.

go make your if statements all look like that

`if choice.lower() == "r" or choice.lower() == "rock":`

Comment: Okay thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome. be sure to accept the answer if it worked out for you